# Cannot switch to 'my tags' tab in unanswered questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, tabs

Steps to reproduce:

- open any unanswered page, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/php The 'newest' tab gets selected
- click on 'my tags' tab

The page reloads, but it is the 'votes' tab which gets selected (although the browser reports the URL as mytags, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/php?tab=mytags)

Using:

```
Google Chrome   11.0.696.57 (Official Build 82915)
WebKit  534.24 (branches/chromium/696@84661)
V8  3.1.8.12
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.57 Safari/534.24
```

The same happens in:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.17) Gecko/20110422 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.17
```

[image: screenshot]

EDIT:
Now I saw the bug doesn't appear if you open a plain unanswered page (no tags selected). You need to select some tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an old redirect that happens because "my tags" *when viewing a tag* doesn't make much sense.  However, it doesn't make much sense to send you to "votes" either.

Starting in the next build, if you click "my tags" when already viewing a tag-specific unanswered list, we'll kick you up to the top "my tags" instead.  For example, from `/unanswered/tagged/php` "my tags" will now take you to `/unanswered?tab=mytags`, resulting in more expected behavior...your tags.